# Can we change setting in the Azure portal so that the VM which is created after failover in Azure ASR has premium disk types?

Tags: azure, replication, failover, azure-site-recovery

Basically, what I need is when a machine is replicated using Azure ASR and a VM is created after Test Failover or Final Failover, the newly created Azure VM should have premium disk types irrespective of on-premise disk type. Can this be achieved by making any changes on the Azure portal ?

Answer (score 0):

While enabling replication for the first time you can mention what type of disks are needed after fail-over.Once you have enabled it you may change thru Powershell from standard to premium, however reverse direction is not supported

Comment: Yes. But is there any option to change from Standard to Premium from portal itself  (not through powershell) after it is replicated.

Comment: The portal, we have option to change it before failover.

Comment: Thanks. Where is that feature ? I am trying to use that for long. Thanks a ton in advance :)

Comment: can you please help with above comment :) ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest option for this is to- First let the VM be created with Standard disks, then shutdown the VM, then go to 'Disks' properties and change the disk/s from Standard to Premium and then restart the VM. Seems, there is no option to let the VM itself be created with Premium disks.